# Вывод сообщений JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какой элемент javaFX предпочтителен для вывода сообщений таким образом, какой показан на экране? Предполагается, что сообщений будет некоторое кол-во, и выводится они будут друг под другом. 
 Так же интересно было бы взглянуть на такой код вывода сообщений. Заранее благодарен

Comment: Если планируется вывод однотипных объектов неопределённого количества то можно использовать ListView. Реализация нетривиальная и, если интересно, я могу подробно описать в ответе. Будет просто если есть опыт работы с ListView из AndroidSDK - тот же принцип.

Answer (score 1):

Компонент `TextArea` должен подойти для Ваших целей.

Рекомендую добавлять сообщения в данный элемент следующим образом:

```
void addTextToTextArea(final String text) { //java 8
        Platform.runLater(() -> this.textArea.appendText(text + '\n'));
}
```